# Norm map of unramified extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, class-field-theory

Let $K \subset L$ be an abelian unramified extension of local fields. Is it true that norm map $N:\mathcal O_L^*\mapsto \mathcal O_K^*$ is surjective?

Comment: The norm map doesn't send $L$ to the units of ${\mathcal O}_K$. You probably meant to write the norm map from ${\mathcal O}_L^\times$ to ${\mathcal O}_K^\times$. Yes, that norm map is surjective.

Comment: Can it be proved using only Artin's reciprocity law?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I mean $\mathcal O_L$

Comment: Artin reciprocity is completely unnecessary.  Since the extension is unramified, the residue field degree equals $[L:K]$ and the Galois group of $L/K$ is naturally isomorphic to the Galois group of the residue field extension. Therefore the norm map from ${\mathcal O}_L$ to ${\mathcal O}_K$ reduces to the norm map on the residue fields.  In this way, surjectivity of the norm map on the units can be derived from surjectivity of the norm map on the nonzero elements of the residue field.

Comment: This result can be found as a corollary in Chapter II section 4 of Lang's Algebraic Number Theory. This result comes long before any discussion of class field theory for local fields.

Comment: I'm almost certain that this is in Serre's _Local Fields_ somewhere.

Comment: As another appraoch, one can use the Tate-cohomology to show the surjectivity by showing the triviality of the first cohomology-group. And I am not completely sure this is different from the above approach. Maybe in the end they are equivalent?

Comment: You can see V.1.2, p. 319, Neukirch's ANT.